# Debug a fake STM32F103C6 using STM32CubeIDE

Tags: debugging, stm32, bare-metal

Is it possible debug the `SMT32F103C6 (BluePill)` using the `STM32CubeIDE` Debug?

My `MCU` is a fake one and I am not sure if it is possible to debug directly on the `STM32CubeIDE`. If some one knows how, could they explain to me?

When I try to debug using the `STM32CubeIDE` the following message appears:

```
Error: Serial number not found. Wrong parameter: sn=6068ff286068ff286068ff28
Encountered Error when opening C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.6.1\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_1.6.0.202101291314\tools\bin\STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe
Error in STM32CubeProgrammer
Debugger connection lost.
```

Comment: the blue pills have historically been made with real stm32s.   you are finding ones with other markings?  what chip is actually on the board?  and what about those datasheets (is it a gd32?)

Comment: Sounds like you've previously used a different STLink. There's a "scan" option in the "Run configurations" window that should (hopefully) pick up your new board.